# What might be causing No Match Call error when compiling C++ code?

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11, lambda

Am receiving an error when compiling this piece of code:

```
void Lift::AddDestFloors(const vector<Person>& persons,
                         vector<int>& fplan,
                         int lift_pos) {
    for (auto &person : persons) {
        int dest_flr = person.dest_floor;
        if (std::find_if(fplan.begin(), fplan.end(),
                         [dest_flr] (const Person& person) -> bool {
                             return person.dest_floor == dest_flr;
                         }) == fplan.end()) {
            InsertToMasterFlightPlan(person.dest_floor, fplan);
        }
    }
}
```

**Error message:**

> ```
> no match for call to '(Lift::AddDestFloors(const std::vector&,
> std::vector&, int)::__lambda0) (int&)'
> LiftSim     line 208, external location: 
> c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h  C/C++ Problem
> ```

**My environment is:**

- Windows 7,
- Eclipse (Kepler)
- Mingw 4.8.1

Why do I get this error?

Comment: Presumably you meant `std::find_if(persons.begin(), persons.end(), ...`? Your lambda takes a `Person` not an `int`.

Comment: No, it isn't, that's just the location of the lambda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error means that some value of type `(Lift::AddDestFloors(const std::vector&, std::vector&, int)::__lambda0)` is called with `int` as argument, but the object cannot be called with an `int` value. (For example, if you have a lambda that takes a `bool`, you cannot call it with an `int` as argument).

The only lambda in your code is the argument to `find_if`: `[dest_flr](const Person& person)->bool {return person.dest_floor == dest_flr;})`

You're calling `find_if` on `fplan`. `fplan` has an element type of `int`, so that lambda should also take an `int`, not a `Person`.